# Mallory stops capturing with Segmentation fault Debug: UDPprotocol[m]?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, appsec, proxy

I have configured mallory on Kali VM to intercept traffic originating from my Windows 7 VM. I am running dnsmasq on the internet facing interface on the kali machine (acting as dns server address from Windows 7) and the other interface is acting as a gateway for the Windows 7 machine. The issue is whenever I start capture, mallory shows Segmentation faults and stops capture. Is there any configuration change to be made for dnsmasq.conf file, resolv.conf file etc.?

Comment: Can you post the full output from Mallory. Or at the very least the last lines before the crash. Although unless this is part of mallory design this is as much a general debug question as Information Security.

Comment: seg faults are not normally caused by configuration of other programs - also, I'm not sure how we can troubleshoot knowing only "there was an error"

Answer (score 1):

After encountering a similar issue, I suspect you might not have installed Mallory's certificate in Windows. This is located in

```
mallory/current/src/ca
```

Installing this resolved the seg faults I received when testing iOS.

Comment: Even though mallory was installed on Kali, the certificate needs to be installed on the Windows host?